# Is Pub nub hosted on Amazon or on private cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pubnub

Trying to look for messaging solution for the app that we are building and planning to host on Amazon. Is pubnub also hosted in Amazon?

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub Data Centers

> **Amazon EC2**, **IBM Softlayer**, **Rackspace** and **Microsoft Azure** and plans for **Google Cloud**.

Where are clients connecting to when I deploy my application with PubNub?
PubNub is a globally distributed Publish/Subscribe communications Cloud. PubNub operates in multiple cloud vendor providers including Amazon EC2, IBM Softlayer, Rackspace and Microsoft Azure. Currently, PubNub is deployed in eighteen (18) EC2 availability zones across six (6) Amazon geographical regions:

1. EU Central
2. EU West
3. Asia Pacific
4. US West
5. US East
6. South America

Client connections are automatically routed and handled by the nearest data center for optimal response and throughput speeds.

[Where are PubNub servers located?](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/486/where-are-pubnub-servers-located)

[What is the impact on my PubNub-powered application due to a data center failure?](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/384/what-happens-if-a-data-center-fails)